# Multiple DataKeyNames from Complex type in GridView with ObjectDataSource

Tags: gridview, data-binding

I have an `List<Examination>` datasource where each record contains two objects. I want to bind datakeynames property with the pkIds of both objects e.g.

```
<asp:GridView DataKeyNames="obj1.pkId, obj2.pkId" ... />
```

I am binding the grid programatically. but I get error indicating:

DataBinding: 'objectList' does not contain a property with the name 'obj1.pkId'

Way around will be much appreciated.

**Edit**

```
class Examination
{
 public string name{get;set;}
 public TestClass test{get;set;}
 public Subject subject{get;set;}
}

class TestClass 
{
public int testId{get;set;}
}

class Subject
{
public int subjectId{get;set;}
}
```

Expected DataKeyNames are **"test.testId, subject.subjectId"** which makes *Examination* class objects unique.

My ObjectDataSource would be bound to `List<Examination>`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.  Using the index value as described in the comments above by deostroll did not work.

I found the solution to my problem [here instead](http://forums.asp.net/t/1456586.aspx/1).

I chose to implement a property at the root object level to represent the id of the child object.

To match the example above, the code would look like this:

```
    class Examination
    {
        public string name{get;set;}
        public TestClass test{get;set;}
        public Subject subject{get;set;}
        public int TestID { get { return test.testId; } }
        public int SubjectID { get { return subject.subjectId; } }
    }

    class TestClass 
    {
       public int testId{get;set;}
    }

    class Subject
    {
       public int subjectId{get;set;}
    }
```

Then, to set the datakeys on my gridview in the markup of the grid, 
**DataKeyNames="name, TestID, SubjectID"**.